# How do I parse multiples XML file with Python and save them into a CSV file?

Tags: python, xml, csv, dictionary

I completely new at programming and Python language. I am trying to parse many XML to get some data an to save it as a CSV file. The is that my code (built from different cases I saw in Stack Overflow) parses just the last one file in the directory (path). What am I doing bad? Is there a problem with indentation o the code order?

The code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import os


fields = [
    ('300$a', 'volume'), ('300$b', 'numero'), ('300$c', 'parte'), ('300$d', 'pag'),
    ('245$a', 'title-group/article-title[1]'), ('242$a', 'title-group/article-title[2]'), ('242$y', 'lng'),
    ('024$a', 'article-id[@pub-id-type="doi"]'),
    ('041$a', 'lng'),
    ('590$a', 'Art'), ('590$b', 'focus'),
    ('546$a', 'lng_abstract'),
    ('520$a', 'abstract/p[1]'), ('520$a', 'abstract/p[2]'), ('520$a', 'abstract/p[3]'),
    ('Surname_1', 'contrib-group/contrib[1]/name/surname'),
    ('Given_1', 'contrib-group/contrib[1]/name/given-names'),
    ('Surname_2', 'contrib-group/contrib[2]/name/surname'),
    ('Given_2', 'contrib-group/contrib[2]/name/given-names'),
    ('Surname_3', 'contrib-group/contrib[3]/name/surname'),
    ('Given_3', 'contrib-group/contrib[3]/name/given-names'),
    ('Surname_4', 'contrib-group/contrib[4]/name/surname'),
    ('Given_4', 'contrib-group/contrib[4]/name/given-names')]

path = r'E:\Files\Nueva Carpeta'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
    continue

fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)

tree = ET.parse(fullname)
root = tree.getroot()

with open('article-meta.csv', 'w') as f_article:
    csv_article_meta = csv.DictWriter(f_article, fieldnames=[field for field, match in fields])
    csv_article_meta.writeheader()

    for node in tree.iter('article-meta'):
        row = {}

        for field_name, match in fields:
            try:
                row[field_name] = node.find(match).text
            except AttributeError as e:
                row[field_name] = ''

    csv_article_meta.writerow(row)
```

And the XML looks like:

```
<article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<front>
.
.
.
    <article-meta>
        <article-id>S0104-40602017000700027</article-id>
        <article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1590/0104-4060.52923</article-id>
        <title-group>
            <article-title xml:lang="pt">
                <![CDATA[
                    A inclusão das pessoas com deficiência: panorama inclusivo no ensino superior no Brasil e em Portugal
                    ]]>
        </article-title>
        <article-title xml:lang="en">
        <![CDATA[
            Inclusion of people with disabilities: Inclusive panorama in higher education in Brazil and Portugal
            ]]>
        </article-title>
        </title-group>
            <contrib-group>
                <contrib contrib-type="author">
                    <name>
                        <surname>
                            <![CDATA[ Pereira ]]>
                        </surname>
                        <given-names>
                            <![CDATA[ Carlos Eduardo Candido ]]>
                        </given-names>
                        </name>
                        <xref ref-type="aff" rid="Aff"/>
                </contrib>
                <contrib contrib-type="author">
                    <name>
                        <surname>
                            <![CDATA[ Albuquerque ]]>
                        </surname>
                        <given-names>
                            <![CDATA[ Cristina Maria Pinto ]]>
                        </given-names>
                        .
                        .
                        .
    </article-meta>
</front>
```

I'm sorry for English, I'm learning it.

Comment: Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Yes: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

I copied the code you have posted and eliminate in my code the part that you have mentioned in your answer. I tried to do the same but including it and the TypeError stills.

Comment: Where does the TypeError occur?

Comment: I got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Scielo_Xpath/Code.py", line 29, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 584, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

If you prefer, I'll edit my question and post the new code and error.

Comment: Aaah I see the problem. `xml_file_paths` is a _list_ of files, `ET.parse` works on a _single_ file at a time. You need some sort of looping logic to parse every file.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it! 
Do you know any tutorial or Python documentation that helps me? If not, I'm thinking of parse a file at a time and write a new code to joins all the CSV in one.

Comment: I don't know of any docs that would help with this specifically, but I am currently tweaking it a bit to see if it'll run!

Comment: I tried something else, but I’m now going to do this with BeautifulSoup. Do you have an example of the desired output? Also, is it guaranteed that there will never be more than four contributors?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderCécile, I'm sorry about be late. 

No, at least a contributor, but can be appear more. There are other tags repeteable, like abstract, kwd or institution. (see: http://scielo.iec.gov.br/scieloOrg/php/articleXML.php?pid=S2176-62232019000100010&lang=pt)

Would you agree if I upload a exemple to folder I shared with you? I could prepare it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for filename in os.listdir(path):
if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
    continue

fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

In the above code you iterate over all the files, skipping those which aren't XML, but you aren't doing anything if the file is indeed an XML file! `filename` is the variable representing the current item during iteration, so when you later write `os.path.join(path, filename)`, `filename` is always the value of the last item from `listdir`.

Here is a rough sketch of how you could get the paths of all the XML files:

```py
xml_file_paths = [os.path.join(path, curr_f_name) for curr_f_name in os.listdir(path) if curr_f_name.endswith('.xml')]
```